# Multiple Websites/Stores, same Skus, different attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, product-attribute, websites

I have 3 different websites, each with it's own store. **WebA.com**/**WebA_en**, **WebB.com**/**WebB_en**, and **WebC.com**/**WebC_en**.

I have somewhere close to 10,000 skus. Some of these skus belong to two, or all three of my stores. All of my skus share the same stock quantity. The skus that belong to two or all three of my websites may or may not have different attributes depending on the website. Image, Tiered Pricing, Minimum Sale and Interval Quantities, Description, Price, etc. must all be dependant on the store they belong to.

**Example**

0001 Is on **WebA.com/WebA_en** as well as **WebB.com/WebB_en** but not **WebC.com/WebC_en**.

0001 on **WebA.com/WebA_en** costs $2.50, has tier pricing available, a minimum sale quantity, and a quantity increment set. The base image on this store is an in-package image.

0001 on **WebB.com/WebB_en** costs $5.00, does not have tier pricing available, has no minimum sale quantity (1), and has no quantity increment set (1). The base image on this store is an out-of-package closeup.

I am using Magento 1.9 CE.

My questions are:

Does Magento come with any of these features out of the box?

What features will I need in addition to innate functionality?

Are there readily available extensions that can help me?

What kind of problems can I expect when it comes to import/export?

I am an experienced developer, but as this is the first time I am working with this level of multisite/multistore functionality, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, create a Magento Website per Web? site and a relevant store view. Then switch on Website Pricing in Configuration. You just need to play with all the settings from there at the store level.

Answer (score 1):

Magento have great feasibility with Attributes. When You create a new attribute then you can define what will be scope of that attribute means if scope is store, then you can put different values on store level for that particular attribute.

If your attribute scope is website then you can put different value on website level for that particular attribute means on store level you can not have different value under a particular website.

If your attribute scope is global then you will have same value for all the stores and website.

But there are some attribute which you will have by default into a default magento installation which you may need to use. But you can differentiate value of those attributes per scope of those attribute.

And you can not edit these default attributes scope from the admin panel. If you needed to do that then you have make changes into database.

For find attach screenshot where you can the scope of the attributes.

[image]